# Printing number triangle on the console in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, printing, sequence

I have a program which prints a sequence of numbers, each on a new line. I want to ask how can I print the lines in reversed order. For example for n=5, the program should output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Here is the source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    while (n!=1)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            cout<<i<<' ';

        }
        cout<<endl;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the output you get now? Have you tried to sit down with a pen and some paper to try and figure it out first?

Comment: Just decrement instead of increment? i-- instead of i++, start with printing n=5, stop at 0?

Comment: This does seem trivial. Perhaps you should read a bit more and try it yourself a few times.

Comment: Search first before posting.  You can find a lot of examples by using the search text: "StackOverflow C++ print triangle"

Answer (score 0):

Try counting up to `n`.

You can, for example, replace the `while` loop by a `for` loop counting up to `n`.